FBGEMM load error trying to use PyTorch on Windows
I'm working on a code that uses Whisper, and I need PyTorch with CUDA to improve the speed of the model execution, I have CUDA installed (verified using nvidia-smi command where it shows that I have CUDA 12.6) and I installed PyTorch using the command pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121, but when I try to import torch in Python (import torch) I get the error:

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\Windows10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I tried uninstalling PyTorch completely and reinstalling several times but it didn't work, apparently the installation is successful but for some reason Python cannot access it, i have Python 3.11.3. Any help is appreciated

fbgemm is a host side library internal to libtorch, it doesn't have anything to do with CUDA. If you search you should find it is a common problem usually solved by installing the necessary host runtime support

I don't know if that is the problem, when i see the .dll using dependency walker there are many missing dependencies (almost 170), among them are API-MS-WIN and EXT-MS-WIN, dependencies that should be part of Windows, i don't know how fix that

update: I have used another program and it says that the missing .dll is "libomp140.x86_64.dll", any idea how to fix it?

That is a Visual C++ runtime component. You you search you will find other people with a similar issue and what they did to solve

I install (and reinstall) all visual studio componets with a other programs (oneAPI Base Toolkit) and didn't works, I had to manually download and put the missing .dll into System32 in order to use Pytorch

I found a solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78794748/10549172

https://github.com/sayol/PyTorch.2.4.0-Error-Solved

Uninstalled all:
pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

Then installed the one-step older version:
pip install torch==2.3.0 torchvision==0.18.0 torchaudio==2.3.0

Now, it's working fine.
Initially, I got this problem after the installation of torchvision, torch was working fine before that.

Cool, so the latest version of pyTorch is just missing .dll. Thank you.

To not miss the CUDA capabilities, add --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 to the end for these versions.

indeed, older version is working for me. Thank you!

Uninstall torch 2.4.0 and reinstall torch 2.3.0, torchvision 0.18.0 as described in this answer works me. Thank you!

as you have found out yourself, let's summarize it briefly because it's difficult to read the solution between comments.
To fix this problem we need to add the missing dependency libomp140.x86_64.dll to the C:\Windows\System32 directory. To achieve this, we need to install the C++ build tools, as pointed out in: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/131662#issuecomment-2252589253.
Follow the issue in the official PyTorch repository on GitHub to stay up to date on this issue: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/131662
EDIT: will be fixed in version 2.4.1

This solution works, following a post in the github link. Here is a short summary, using the Visual Studio Installer, go to individual components, find MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest) and add this package.

installing "(Latest) tools build x64/x86 C++ 2022 VS - v143MSVC" using the Visual Studio Installer worked for me. I was trying to use openai-whisper (eg pip install -U openai-whisper), not pytorch directly.

Simply installing Visual Studio 2022 and making sure I selected the data science toolset in the workloads install menu worked for me. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

https://github.com/sayol/PyTorch.2.4.0-Error-Solved

Here is what worked for me:
pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

pip install torch==2.3.0 torchvision==0.18.0 torchaudio==2.3.0 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

I am on Windows, using free pycharm, no conda. My GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Ti

I had python 3.11 installed on the machine, so I downloaded python 3.9.1 and established my environment, selecting 3.9 and downloading the requirements in that venv which fixed my issue.

Just Don't use virtual enviornment bcoz as you know some modules/libraries have conflict among them so if used together they won't work try and run it from your PC and not Virtual enviornment it worked for me it'll work for you too..

Using a virtual environment is a best practice. It isolates dependencies, preventing conflicts between different projects.

I’m confused by your answer: if some modules/libraries have conflicts, then it’s good to install them in a virtual, isolated environment and not in the global environment of your computer.

I had this same problem a few hours ago when trying to use PyTorch. This problem is related to some incompatibility between the CUDA version and PyTorch version on Windows. The way I solved it was by uninstalling everything related to Nvidia (even the graphics drivers) and installing CUDA Toolkit Version 12.4 and cuDNN Version 9.2.1. This setup works well with PyTorch 2.4.0. Another thing that was missing on my system was Microsoft Visual Studio, which CUDA uses for certain tasks. I found a tutorial on YouTube that taught me how to do it from beginning to end. It even shows how to download PyTorch correctly. It helped me a lot.
Just for the record, before doing this, my drivers were exactly like yours. My GPU is a 1660 Ti.
